# Как при выборе select заменить несколько значений input в форме?

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь создать одну форму оплаты paypal но с разными суммами и валютами (RUB, USD и т.д.).

При выборе select необходимо **прописать несколько** input в форме.

Код ниже заменяет только input amount

```
<select required name="amount" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Choose sum</option>
  <option value="10">USD 10</option>
  <option value="100">RUB 100</option>  
</select>
```

Как-то можно используя данный select или на основе `$paypal_item_number`, заменить не только **amount** но и item_number, currency_code, validity в форме?

Сейчас если в базе данных несколько вариантов оплаты, в форме изменяется только сумма и все, а необходимо почти все в ней изменить.

Мой код:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$payment_service = $row["payment_service"];

if ($payment_service == 'PayPal'){
    $paypal_item_number = $row["id"];
    $paypal_amount = $row["amount"];
    $paypal_curr_code = $row["currency_code"];
    $validity = $row["validity"];
    $paypal_email = $row["paypal_email"];
    //var_dump($row);

  $money[] = <<<HTML
  <option value="$paypal_amount">$paypal_curr_code $paypal_amount</option>
HTML;

  }
}

// Include paypal form
include __DIR__ . '/forms/paypal.php';
```

Форма:

```
<form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
                    <select required name="amount" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Choose sum</option>
<?php                           
foreach( $money as $key => $value ) {
    print  $value;
}
?>  
                    </select>

                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_email; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $validity; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $productName; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $paypal_item_number; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $paypal_curr_code; ?>">
                    

                                        
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?return" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?cancel_return" />

                    <!-- Where to send the paypal IPN to. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>pin-checker/engine/paypal_ipn.php?orderDataID=<?php echo $paypal_item_number; ?>" /> 
<button type="submit" name="submit">
    Buy Now With PayPal        
</button>                        
</form>
```

Что-то намудрил и  запутался.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://snipp.ru/jquery/jquery-select https://snipp.ru/jquery/input-text-jquery

Comment: Спасибо, почти разобрался, осталось понять как при помощи select менять один массив данных на другой и подставлять его в форму. Выбрал пример "Добавить элементы option в select из массива".